# Backbone Collection fetch Options not effecting GET Request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, couchdb

I Have the following Backbone Collection Code :

```
AssessmentSlos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: "mapping",

      db: {
        view: "slosByAssessmentId"
      },
      fetch: function(options) {
        options = {};
        options.data ={};
        options.data.date = "2013-10";
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
      }
    });
```

THe Code For initializing and calling fetch is this

```
c = new AssessmentSlos();
c.fetch();
```

Expected/Correct URL Request Should Be like this one

```
http://localhost:5984/tangerine/_design/tangerine/_view/slosByAssessmentId?date=2011-10
```

But When i inspect i get this:

```
http://localhost:5984/tangerine/_design/tangerine/_view/slosByAssessmentId?cacheBuster=126
```

Why My Date Query is not showing in the url query ?
I followed this simple guide http://japhr.blogspot.in/2011/10/overriding-url-and-fetch-in-backbonejs.html

According to the guide this code should be working. What is my mistake ?

Comment: Try replacing this code- options.data = {date: this.date}; with this one - options.data.date = this.date;

Comment: `this.date` is `undefined` so it will not be passed as a param.

Comment: Just add `date` property to your collection and ensure it is set, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6wup7q9e/1/) I added `date` and I can see it in the GET request.

Comment: I fixed the undefined date to a fix string but the problem is same , One more thing i did is, I copied this code and pasted on backbone.js console and it's working but here on my application it's not working http://m.teletaaleem.com/tangerine/_design/tangerine/index.html#login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with backbone, it's the  backbone-couchdb connector which was changing my fetch parameters,So to achieve it I added query's to the "db" object of collection class, e.g fetching on keys will be like this

```
AssessmentSlos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: "mapping",

      db: {
        view: "slosByAssessmentId"
        ,keys: ["2013-10"]

      },
      fetch: function(options) {
        options = {};
        options.data ={};
        options.data.date = "2013-10";
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
      }
    });
```